# Trouble adding custom button to navigation controller's toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a tableview controller that has a navigation controller. I have added a toolbar to the bottom of the view and now I need to add a custom button. I have the following code (from viewDidLoad), which is producing strange results. When the view loads, I see the custom button for a brief second, then an empty toolbar. At the moment I am only trying to get one custom button to load.

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[self.navigationController.toolbar sizeToFit];

CGFloat toolbarHeight = [self.navigationController.toolbar frame].size.height + 20;

[self.navigationController.toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(CGRectGetMinX(self.view.bounds),
                                                       CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.bounds) - toolbarHeight,
                                                       CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds),
                                                       toolbarHeight)];


UIBarButtonItem *btn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage
                        imageNamed:@"stub_fav.png"]
                        style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                        target:self action:@selector(addFavorite)];

[btn setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stub_fav.png"]];

NSArray *toolbarItems = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:btn, nil];
[self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:toolbarItems];
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what btnAddFave is for but it's not the subview of anything. I assume btw and btnAddFave should have the same background image, if so you spelled stub_fav.png wrong. shouldn't it be stub_fave.png

Comment: Sorry, I edited the original post. btnAddFave is no longer in the code sample

Comment: can you see the toolbar? you shouldn't have [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stub_fav.png"]];

Comment: Yes, I can see the toolbar, but it is empty

Comment: kk, first delete [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stub_fav.png"]]; and then add UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]; and change your toobarItems to initwithobjects: btn, flexSpace,nil] and then sizeToFit your toolbar